# Laravel 5.4 need to get distinct records through eloquent relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4, eloquent, distinct-values

I have a table "transactions". in that table I have multiple columns which are id, user_id, customer_name, restaurant_name and time-stamps also.
What I need is if I have two or three same records in the table means restaurant_name is repeating with the same user_id. I need to get only unique records. If user ordered from same restaurant 3 times I need to get only 1 from those.

**Example:**
If I order form Pizza Hut 3 time and ordered from Subway 5 times. The result should contain 1 pizza hut and 1 subway.

**Note:** 1 user may have many transactions

**Transaction Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\restaurant;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function restaurant(){
        return $this->belongsTo(restaurant::class);
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','customer_name', 'restaurant_name' , 'ordered_items' , 
    ];
}
```

**User Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\restaurant;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function restaurant(){
        return $this->belongsTo(restaurant::class);
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','customer_name', 'restaurant_name' , 'ordered_items' , 
    ];
}
```

I am trying to getting desired results like this but It is showing me an error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method distinct does not exist.

$user->transactions->distinct("restaurant_name");
```

Comment: Your `User` model has no relation to `Transaction`? I have a feeling you miss copied your code because there are two `Transaction` classes.

Comment: Sorry about that. User model have this function ...

Comment: class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function transactions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }
}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`distinct` is not an existing function for Laravel collections, but [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique) is.

```
$user->transactions->unique("restaurant_name");
```

However that will query all transactions and filter in code. To get the distinct rows using a query, you could do the following:

```
$user->transactions()->groupBy('restaurant_name')->get();
```

Comment: You are unique also to give this fantastic answer ... :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :) Consider marking this answer as the solution so other users might also find this.